# Adding new columns in list-dataframes using lapply() based on other list-elements

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of dataframes, where all elements have short index-names. I'm trying to add a new column to certain dataframes containing their real names based on an index-dataframe in the list containing the indices (key) and real names (names).

I actually thought this is a pretty easy task until I ran intro trouble with the indices of the assignment part of the code as shown below:

```
# sample data
data_list <- list(data.frame(names=c("iris", "TootgGrowth", "airquality"), key=c("name01", "name02", "name03")),
                  iris, ToothGrowth, airquality)
names(data_list) <- c("index", "name01", "name02", "name03")

# adding a new column to selected list-dataframes
data_list[names(data_list) != "index"] <-
  lapply(names(data_list)[names(data_list) != "index"],
       function(x){data_list[x]$new_col <- data_list$index$names[data_list$index$key == x]})
```

The part `data_list$index$names[data_list$index$key == x]` gives me the correct values I'd like to assign, but I have still no clue how to correctly index in the `data_list[x]$new_col <-` part, so that the assignment works. I also tried to use `assign(paste0("data_list$", x, "$new_col"), ...)`, which also doesn't work obviously.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
lapply(names(data_list), function(x) {
   if (x != "index")
     cbind(data_list[[x]],new_col = data_list$index$names[data_list$index$key == x])
   else
     data_list[[x]]
})
```

If `name` of the list element is "index" then we return the dataframe as it is and if it is not then we add a `new_col` to the dataframe with it's name.

Comment: I actually didn't think of cbind here -facepalm-. Thanks for the solution, works great!